# Angle between earth's angular momentum and earth's axis

Tags: the-sun, earth

I think this picture is correct because for earth astronomical day is slightly shorter than solar day. (Is it a rule of thumb for planets? Where can I read such data?)

[image] [Source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Sidereal_day_(prograde).svg)

So the angle between earth's angular momentum and earth's axis(from south pole to north pole) is 23.5° and not a (180°-23.5°).

That is why observer is standing on the sun in the next picture. And the break in circle-shaped arrows is closer to the sun, then the rest of arrow.

Am I right? Thanks!

[image]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8F22.jpg)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. The Earth rotates around its axis, so it has spin angular momentum, and it revolves around the Sun, so it also has orbital angular momentum. The angle between those two axes is called the [obliquity of the ecliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic#Obliquity_of_the_ecliptic).

Comment: @PM Your comment is an answer to the question. The terms "orbital angular momentum" and "obliquity of the ecliptic". The rest may be googled. Also do you agree with the last sentence of the question? "That is why..."

Comment: I rather doubt that the "breaks in arrows" is there for anything other than clarity of the direction.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Do we see the disk from the top or from the bottom?(rhetorical question) I am sure that from the top.(arguments are presented).

Comment: @ged from the top.  If we looked from the bottom, we'd see Great A'Tuin